# Dynamically Populate Content Within Un-Orthodox Grid

Tags: html, css

I'm currently developing out a blog page with a 3 X 3 grid layout for content to fall into the different boxes (see attached example).

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/337/cssex.jpg/

The content blocks in the lighter gray are meant to be stationary, so any updated, recently added, etc. content will not affect these boxes, only the black ones. I'm trying to figure out the best approach with keeping the gray boxes stationary, but allowing the black boxes to be populated dynamically (WordPress blog entries) and floating naturally through the layout.

As of now, I'm thinking that each individual black box will query the recent post that aligns to it. So, the first black box would query the most recent post, the second black box would query the second recent post and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A big order!

Here is the general idea to help get you going:

1. You need to make those blocks a `<div>` or `<section>` with an ID tag like this:

   ```
   <section id=brief1>
   ```

   (BTW, you can also use a "table" & merge cells to get that layout, just ensure you use an ID)
2. Then you need find a script to update the `innerHTML` using straight JavaScript, or a JS library like jQuery, MooTools, etc.  This will allow you to inject text &/or an image inside those boxes.  Example search: http://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+update+innerHTML+div
3. Once you have 1 spot updated with text, it is time to edit that script. Make an array of our ID tags, then loop though all of them to insert new content one at a time.

Good luck! If I see something pre-rolled on my travels, I'll update this thread.